# apex:outputLink attribute "disabled" not working?

Tags: outputlink

I'm trying to get output links while using the disabled attribute, but my page is still rendering them as anchor tags, not spans as the salesforce documentation says it should be.

Code is as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="availableImages">
    <apex:repeat value="{!images}" var="image">
        <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!image.Id}" disabled="true">{!image.Name}</apex:outputLink>
        <apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!image.Id}" width='250' height='250'></apex:image>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Am I missing something really obvious here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your above mentioned code is working perfectly alright in my developer org. Probably there is something else which you might be missing.

Comment: Worth adding a screenshot